torch DataParallel model predict same data is different between single GPU or CPU
problem
I have use torch.nn.DataParallel to use multi GPU train model, but I notice, when I use two cuda to calculate result , it is different from use single cuda or cpu. It is stange, and I don`t know why, please tell me how to fix it or explain it.
system
PyTorch: 2.0.0+cu117
CUDA Version: 12.0
result
You can use follow code to reproduce  this problem， and it will print like this, Multi-card results are very different from single-card results or CPU results.



multi GPU
single GPU
CPU




0.436291307
0.307008564
0.307096988


0.618099451
0.502333581
0.498412549


-0.230154008
-0.209866986
-0.206241921


-0.556713521
-0.558704913
-0.555095673


-0.30781576
-0.209164187
-0.211295918


-0.410598308
-0.512709379
-0.513415456


0.298149496
0.474029034
0.468837589


-0.270193249
-0.148075178
-1.52E-01


-0.05058343
-0.017191991
-0.019832365


0.619232118
6.59E-01
6.56E-01


-0.036778659
-0.135650381
-0.132507876



code

import torch
import torchvision

def load_data(num_gpus):
    transforms = torchvision.transforms.Compose([
    torchvision.transforms.Resize(256),
    torchvision.transforms.CenterCrop(224),
    torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
    torchvision.transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
                                                 ])
#     dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root='datasets/cifar-10-python.tar.gz', transform=transforms)
    dataset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10('datasets', train=True,  transform=transforms,download=True)

    dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        dataset=dataset,
        batch_size=64,
        shuffle=False,
        num_workers=4*num_gpus
                                                )
    return dataloader



model = torchvision.models.resnet50(pretrained=False)
model = model.cuda()
model = torch.nn.parallel.DataParallel(model, device_ids=[0,1], dim=0)

dataloader = load_data(2)

m_s = model.module.state_dict()

model1 = torchvision.models.resnet50(pretrained=False)
model1.load_state_dict(m_s)


model2 = torchvision.models.resnet50(pretrained=False)
model2.load_state_dict(m_s)
model2 = model2.to('cuda:2')

for images, labels  in dataloader:
    break


multi_gpu = model(images.cuda())
cpu_predict = model1(images)
s_gpu = model2(images.to('cuda:2'))

a = multi_gpu.reshape(-1).cpu()
b = cpu_predict.reshape(-1)
c = s_gpu.reshape(-1).cpu()

for i,j,k in zip(a,b,c):
    print(i.item(),j.item(),k.item())


call .eval() on the models after you load the state dict

I know when use eval() it will be same, But I want to compare train mode inference result. They are different= =

It's because you didn't call eval() function. The dropout layer is a stocastic process. In each run the outputs will be randomly set to 0, based on your preset probabilities. Unless you call eval() function to disable this behavior, I bet your models will output different results after each run even if they are using the same device.

Thks for your answer. But for this question, I want to fix another train process problem and show this code demo. My problem is why multi GPU train inference result is very different from single GPU result. Considerate dropout layer,  single GPU  train result is little different from CPU train result.
